# Correctly converting datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a datetime string from an XML file ('2016-12-22T21:00:00Z') from this format, I'm using the strptime code ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z") but it's giving me an error.

```
ran = ('2016-12-22T21:00:00Z')
convert = ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(ran, convert)
print(time)
ValueError: time data '2016-12-22T21:00:00Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z
```

After reading all the Q/A's on the website I thought that should be the right code but it appears I'm missing something simple. I just want a format I can use to plot on a graph, I know it's probably an easy fix but I can't figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `%` before `Z` in the format. As `%Z` stands for time zone name/abbreviation in string format such as *UTC, EST, CST* with a [Full List here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), and the letter *Z* by itself does not match any timezone, you need to match it as a letter.

```
import datetime
ran = ('2016-12-22T21:00:00Z')
convert = ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(ran, convert)

time
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 22, 21, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something simple I was missing.